# Erlang in-memory linked list -- Exhausting memory?

Tags: erlang, linked-list, heap-memory

I tried to make an Erlang in-memory datastore that would receive messages and add them to a list. Here's the current incarnation. The trouble is, I'm receiving about 200 messages per second and this easily exhausts the memory available.

Once a minute, I send a {write, Pid} message that should clear out and clean up this list, but it doesn't look like it's being garbage collected.

What am I doing wrong? I think I'm approaching this from the completely wrong direction...

```
datastore(Db) ->
    receive
        {put, Data} ->
            datastore(lists:concat([Data,Db]));
        {write, Responder} ->
            ScratchName = "ScratchFile.dat",
            {ok, ScratchDevice} = file:open(ScratchName,[write]),
            file:write(ScratchDevice,Db),
            ok = file:close(ScratchDevice),
            Responder ! {load, ScratchName},
            datastore([])
    end.
```

Comment: *Update*: This isn't the complete code. I'm receiving messages over TCP and need to write to a file once a minute.

Comment: Just off topic may be but Erlang good practice, you don't need `lists:concat([Data,Db])` because you are using `file:write(ScratchDevice,Db)` where `Db` can be `io_list` which means `[Data|Db]` or `[Data, Db]` will make exactly same work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First spontaneous comment is that file:open will open the file, **truncate** it, and then write to it. So every time in the loop will overwrite any previous data.  So if the Responder is slow with its loading of the file, there could be data you did not expect in the file.

Second reaction is that you don't have to do this buffering yourself.  If you open the file with the option {delayed_write, Size, Delay}, and set Size and Delay to values that fit your purpose, you get precisely what you are trying to implement here by just writing all the time.

Third reaction is that you are probably doing the wrong thing if you use a file to communicate between different parts of your system.  What are you attempting to do?

ps.

If you need a new random filename, you can easily generate one with erlang:now/0 and io_lib:format/2.  As an added bonus they will sort in creation order.

Comment: I work for a large company, so obviously there are some parts to this that I left out. I have random filenames and intend to overwrite each time, so this shouldn't be a problem. The delayed write I'll have to look into, though, because that looks particularly appealing. Thanks

Comment: ...In general practice, though, is this an okay method for buffering?

Comment: It depends.  If I need to write something to file I normally buffer it using delayed_write if I need more speed.  If not losing data is more important than speed I write without buffering.

Comment: I'd make the datastore function a gen_server instead though.  And cast to it.  (And like I said, since you send the filename back to some other process you are probably doing-it-wrong(tm). Need more detail to answer that.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wrong way of buffering in Erlang. Data Structures such as `ETS` (`http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html`) have been designed to handle thousands and millions of IN-MEMORY Erlang Data Structures with ease. Please, do not use `Lists` or `Queues` for handling too much data. If a part of your code will be handling data which other parts of the application are supposed to consume and yet you know that the consumers will be doing it a slower rate as compared to the part that is generating or getting the data, then you need a more robust way of buffering (`ETS Tables`).
Another thing is that usually, processes are a point of failure in a system. If a process is used to buffer or hold on to very essential data, even if that data is instantaneous but critical to the system, what would happen at that time when the process exits or dies ? ETS tables have been designed in a way that they can provide data access to all processes even applications within the same VM (of type `public`). In this way, all processes can use the data, reading as much as they want (concurrently) but what you would do is to ensure consistency by having one writer / updater.
ETS Tables rarely fail in an application as compared to the frequency at which processes fail. Most recently, a method that helps us to redeem data in a failing ETS table has been introduced ( `ets:give_away/3` ).

Another thing, in a comment above, you have mentioned that you are working for a large Company. Usually, with large teams, its better you evaluate a number of options and make intensive tests against several depending the nature of the application you are developing. To avoid side effects, its best that you identify which data structures are best to use for what. For example, for in-memory storage, capable of handling 200 messages per second, if tested properly, `Lists` and `Files` would **fail** against `ETS Tables`.